# Has anyone created any Angular2 auth wrapper classes for IdentityServer 3/4?

Tags: angular, thinktecture-ident-server, identityserver3

i see angular2-jwt but i don't know how to use it with IdentityServer.  has anyone done anything with angular2 and identityserver?

Comment: this is what i've got so far... maybe you can find something in here useful.


gist:https://gist.github.com/curlyfro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it working after following the example's in this blog post:
https://damienbod.com/2016/03/02/angular2-openid-connect-implicit-flow-with-identityserver4/

Comment: Link-only answers are generally [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/204922) on Stack Overflow. In time it is possible for links to atrophy and become unavailable, meaning that your answer is useless to users in the future. It would be best if you could provide the general details of your answer in your actual post, citing your link as a reference.